How do I know if my connection is secure?
I have a RDS Aurora MySQL 3 DB and already set the parameter require_secure_transport, and ran this command:
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.session_status
       WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('Ssl_version','Ssl_cipher');

With the correct output of my ssl cipher and version.
Since I have enabled require_secure_transport, why I can still enter the database without parameter "SSL=ENFORCED"
I just want to know why I can enter the database without using that parameter even If i had enabled the require_secure_transport.

how are you entering the DB you need to let us know that first and then we can tell you why can.

My guess is the mysql client tries a secure connection by default, and falls back to insecure if the server doesn't support it.
